# Upgrading .NET Framwork: Do I need to install .NET Framework on Test and Prod servers too?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-4.0, .net-framework-version

I have installed .Net 4.8 on my Dev environment, and changed Target framework of my project to: .NET Framework 4.8 (used to be 4.6)

Do I need to install .NET Framework 4.8 on Test and Prod environments? Or I can just build and publish the code to the test server?

Comment: Run a quick test and immediately you know.

Comment: @LexLi: after migration, I am having some other issues on the dev environment, specifically "system.net.http or one of it's dependency cannot be loaded"... which is of course a different issue and not related to this question.